# Validate ASPxGridView row data before show edit or delete form

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

How to validate data of a row before it shows the Edit/Delete form in ASPx DevExpress Grid View?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the **ASPxGridView.StartRowEditing** event and call the **ASPxGridView.DoRowValidation** method. See the [Data Validation](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/Validation.aspx) demo.